# Java - MySQL: Command from another class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have two questions about using MySQL in Java. I need to use different values in diverse classes of my program, so my first question is if I need to establish connection in every single one of those classes, or can I do it just once in my main? Secondly, I don't understand how I can call an SQL command from another class. I've tried doing a prepareStatement, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have tried doing following. First I made a DBConnection class (I have removed my real user and password values):

```
public class DBConnection {
      public void connect() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://vhost01.srv.aau.dk/db_name";
        String user = "user";
        String password = "password";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connection established");
```

Which I then call from my main:

```
DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
dbConn.connect();
```

Then in my LoginController I want to verify the entered password and username, by comparing it to values in the database. I tried following an answer from another question here on Stack Overflow by doing:

```
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

try{
        String SQL  = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `Clinician` WHERE `username` =? AND `password` = ?;";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pstmt.setString(1, txtUsername.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2, String.valueOf(txtPassword.getText())); 
        ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery();

        if (result.next()){
                lblMessage.setText("Access confirmed!");                
            }else{
                lblMessage.setText("Access denied!");
                 }   
        }

    catch(SQLException e){

    }

    finally{
           pstmt.close();
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I do establish the connection through main, but it doesn't verify the login. Am I missing something, or doing something completely wrong?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Multimodality.view.LoginController.btnLoginAction(LoginController.java:77)
    ... 58 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never catch an exception without handle it. In your case i think you get an exception, which is ignored by your catch block. Change to: `catch(SQLException e){ e.printStacktrace();
    }` and see if you get an exception

Comment: remove the `;` at the end of your SQL statement

Comment: @Jens I doesn't allow me to remove the ; . When I run the code it says: "Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" followed by more than 30 lines of "at ..."

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace to your question using the edit function

Comment: @Jens It's been added! :-)

Comment: See here: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Multimodality.view.LoginController.btnLoginAction(LoginController.java:77)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two variables named `conn`. The first is only available in your `connect()` method and the second one is `null`. So there should be a NullPointerException in the line `pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);`.

You have to move the preparedStatement-stuff into your `DBConnection`class or your `connect()` method must return the connection so that you can use `Connection conn = dbConn.connect();` in your controller class.

**Update:**

```
public Connection connect()...
     ....
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, user, password);
    System.out.println("Connection established");
    return conn;
}
```

and in the contoller class:

```
DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection();
Connection conn = dbConn.connect();

PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

try{
        String SQL  = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `Clinician` WHERE `username` =? AND `password` = ?;";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed that I called them the same thing! I'm not sure if I can move the preparedStatement-stuff into DBConnection class, since I need to run quite many different SQL commands for the whole program to work - the Login is just the first one. Unless I can make it very general, and change the parameters in every class.

How would I return the connection with connect()? Sorry, I'm rather new with Java.